# Can't install Flutter on Mac

Tags: flutter, homebrew

This is the only install that fails, **I have already installed Flutter on 2 other Macs without any issue**.

It's a MBP 15-inch, 2018 running Mojave.

What might interfere with the installation is **SentinelOne, that's installed on this machine and that I can't remove**, so I need to somehow work around it.

Here's flutter doctor:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F203, locale en-BE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
    ✗ libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed. To install with Brew, run:
        brew update
        brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
        brew link usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
    ✗ ios-deploy not installed. To install:
        brew install ios-deploy
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without resolving iOS dependencies with CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        brew install cocoapods
        pod setup
[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

I run brew update and then:

```
$ brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
==> Cloning https://git.sukimashita.com/libusbmuxd.git
Updating /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/usbmuxd--git
From https://git.sukimashita.com/libusbmuxd
   60109fd..6539b02  master     -> origin/master
==> Checking out branch master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 4 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
HEAD is now at 6539b02 iproxy: Fix (newly introduced) timeout errors not being handled
==> ./autogen.sh
Last 15 lines from /Users/me/Library/Logs/Homebrew/usbmuxd/01.autogen.sh:
2019-07-04 13:22:50 +0200

./autogen.sh

./autogen.sh: line 6: libtoolize: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 8: aclocal: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 9: autoheader: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 10: automake: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 11: autoconf: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 14: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to run `brew install libtool automate autoconf` (or uninstall first) I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue few days ago.
First you have not completely installed all the requirements of Android studio and Xcode.These errors stamps from improper installation and configurations.

Follow these steps.

1. Install or reinstall Android Studio -for the latest version
2. Install or reinstall Flutter macOS
   https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos
3. Install or update Xcode - this takes nearly a couple of hours depending on your connections.
4. Once all is installed - you need to run the command Lines to accept the agreements for Xcode and Xcode toolbox.
5. Install cocoa pod also using the command Line as mentioned in the flutter guide.
6. Finally, make sure that your flutter path in located somewhere you can find it and create a `.zshrc` file and expose the path into this file. I recommend /Users/johndoe/Development

`nano ~/.zshrc'

`export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin"`

per my recommendation it would look like this

`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/johndoe/Development/flutter/bin"`

Answer (score -1):

you have to install **brew** for that, first of all you have to run this command and after that run all other command as suggested in flutter doctor result.

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

download **java** from following link and install it.

https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US

Android studio 3.4 is not now supported with flutter, so as of now you can not solve this error.

for More details you can refer this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy-qHlaHr6c

Comment: no android studio 3.5 is supported via the flutter plugin as it was updated

Comment: I think/hope it's obvious from my post that brew is already installed. I have also installed Java. I mentioned that I have already installed Flutter on a few other machines, so I am not a complete noob. My problem is a bit more complex than RTFM.